# Flutter. Получение значения из Future<String>

Tags: строки, flutter, dart, firestore, future

Всем привет, у меня есть текстовый виджет,текст которого должен браться из метода.

```
 Text('\n'+readData(snapshot.data.documents[i]['user']),style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),)
```

Сам метод:

```
Future<String> readData(String id)  async {
DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(id).get() ;
final String first_name =  snapshot.data['Firstname'];
return first_name;
}
```

Но данные соответственно получить не могу, потому что возвращаемое значение Future, а текстовый виджет принимает только String.

К можно вытащить то самое заветное значение?

Пробовал писать методы, что-то вроде этого, а также различные обёртки - результат нулевой. Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
String readData(String id){
  String k;
 Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(id).get().then((test){
     return k=test.data['Firstname'].toString();
  });
  return k;
}
```

Весь код, решаемой задачи:

```
class BodyPhoto extends State<PhotoScreenBody>{

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return 
    StreamBuilder(stream:Firestore.instance.collection('Photo').snapshots(),builder: (context,snapshot){
      return ListView(children:<Widget>[
        for (int i=0;i<snapshot.data.documents.length;i++)
       Card(child: ListTile(
          title: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,children: <Widget>[
            Image(image: Image.network(snapshot.data.documents[i]['photo_url']).image,),
            Text('\n'+snapshot.data.documents[i]['signature']),
            //Text('\n'+readData(snapshot.data.documents[i]['user']).then((String value) => print(value)),style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),),
            Text('\n'+snapshot.data.documents[i]['user'],style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),),
            Text(snapshot.data.documents[i]['date'],style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),)

          ],),
        ),)   
    ]);
    });

  }
}

Future<String> readData(String id)  async {
DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(id).get() ;
final String first_name =  snapshot.data['Firstname'];
return first_name;
}
```

Comment: 1 метод можно засунуть в `FutureBuilder`и получать `snapshot.data` который можно передать в `Text(snapshot.data...)` => будет `NBuilder -> FutureBuilder ->Text`. 2 метод ничего не вернёт... А можно дополнить код с `Text`, откуда там `snapshot.data` и не обращаетесь-ли вы два раза к одной коллекции в бд?

Comment: @MiT, спасибо я попробую. Что касается вопроса - в Text(..) идет обращение к другой коллекции, чтобы получить так называемый id  и поместить его уже в readData(id).

Comment: `documents[i]['user']` это как мне кажется не правильная запись...

Comment: @MiT, дело в том, что в данном случае идет перебор документов циклом 

`for (int i=0;i<snapshot.data.documents.length;i++)`
Их нумерация идет с 0 до n.
Т.е. мы получаем i-й документ и обращаемся к полю ['user'], вытаскивая id.
Делал трассировку, вытаскивает id верно.
А в поставленном вопросе изначально решается задача с доступом к документу по id
 `document(id).get()`

Comment: @MiT, для наглядности добавил полный код, решаемой задачи.

Comment: С FutureBuilder попробовали?

Comment: К сожалению, на текущий момент нет возможности опробовать, но в ближайшее время постараюсь отписать по результатам.